# Have an IF statement constantly check

Tags: vb.net

Is there anyway to have an IF statement constantly checking? I'm working with a List and I need to check if the list count exceeds a variable. I've since noticed the easiest way to make the program run smoothly is to have an IF statement checking constantly while the program is running.

Comment: Your application contains the code that is adding items to the list. Have your code check to see if the size of the lists exceeds the limit every time you add to it. An easy way to do this might be to create a single method that is used to add items to the list and include the `If` statement in that method.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for this would be to change from 'List' to 'BindingList'. This is an event enabled list which will fire events when the list changes:

```
Private WithEvents mList As New System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of String)

Public Sub Main()
    mList.Add("An Item")
End Sub

Private Sub mList_AddingNew(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventArgs) Handles mList.AddingNew
    If mList.Count > 100 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Threshold exceeded")
    End If
End Sub
```

Alernatively you could start a thread / timer that polls this, however you'll have to watch out for synchronization issues.